# How to skip rows with too few column numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have many `.csv` files with data, but some rows can have less columns than I need. I want to skip this rows, and continue reading only these rows with correct number of columns (I know what is correct number of columns).

Unfortunately I must to do it with batch file... any ideas ?

Comment: are your bosses sadistic ? why sticking to such a poor technology for a rather complex task?

Comment: Depends. Will any of the columns be empty? May any column be quoted-containing-a-comma? Why do you keep the "correct number of columns" a secret? Can you edit into your post a few lines of sample data containing pass/fail conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findstr`.

> example.txt
>
> ```
> qwe,ert,"adsad,asdas",1,2
> kks,ssd,qweq,3,4
> asdas,asdd
> as,sdsd,weqw,5,6
> ```

Create a file with search patterns:

> patterns.txt
>
> ```
> [^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*
> [^,]*,[^,]*,"[^"]*",[^,]*,[^,]*
> ```

- line 1: five values separated by comma
- line 2: handle case of a quoted string in the 3rd field

Then search

```
C:\> findstr /rx /g:patterns.txt example.txt
qwe,ert,"adsad,asdas",1,2
kks,ssd,qweq,3,4
as,sdsd,weqw,5,6
```

Parse the output

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /rx /g:patterns.txt example.txt') do (
    echo %%A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering cases where the CSV data contains quoted fields that contain commas on their own, this task is not quite trivial to be realised in pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) scripting, but possible, provided that the CSV files fulfil the following requirements:

- no `*` characters occur in the CSV files;
- no (quoted) fields contain line-breaks;

The following script counts the number of fields/columns per each line/row and processes (echoes) it only in case the predefined value (5) is met; provide the CSV file(s) as command line arguments:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_NUMCOL=5"

for %%F in (%*) do (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~F") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        set /A "COUNT=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!LINE:**=!"=="!LINE!" (
            set "LINE=!LINE:?=!"
            for %%E in ("!LINE:,=","!") do (
                set /A "COUNT+=1"
            )
            if !COUNT! LSS !_NUMCOL! (
                endlocal
            ) else if !COUNT! GTR !_NUMCOL! (
                endlocal
            ) else (
                endlocal
                rem // Process line with correct number of columns:
                echo(%%L
            )
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```